# How to get tensor Shape python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensor

I have an issue with tensors.

```py
X.get_shape() returns (?, ?, ?, 512)
```

Whereas when I try to concatenate X and an other vector `X=Concatenate()([X,X_add])`, it raises the exception.

> A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 32, 32, 512), (None, 256, 256, 64)]

How do I get those shapes in order to use Cropp2D in my resnet.

Comment: The error message states it very clear. To use concatenate, you need to make sure two vectors you are merging have the same shape everywhere except for the axis you are merging. Your vectors clearly don't have those shapes same, you need to restructure them. You can potentially use another convolutional layer(s) with correct kernel size and number of filters to match them.

Comment: Yes but I intend to use cropping2D, therefore I need access to the tensors shape that is indicated in the error, but i can't manage that with tensor.get_shape() since it returns "?" instead of values 32,32 and 256,256.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to reshape tensors before concatenating. But that won't solve your problem here, because the two tensors are of different size: 32*32*512 != 256* 256*64.